Spurious blank page before glossary when modifying \glspagelistwidth or setting the glossary title
I'm using the glossaries package, and I wish to start my glossary on a new page. Without \newpage, \clearpage, or \pagebreak, it starts on the same page as the previous content, which is not what I want. However, adding \newpage, \clearpage, or \pagebreak before the glossary doesn't just move it to the next page, but one further, creating a spurious blank page in between.
The document class is scrartcl, so it's not due to chapters.
I found multiple ways of getting rid of the spurious blank page, but all of them conflict with how I want the document to look:

not setting the \extrarowheight using the array package
not loading xcolor
not modifying the width of the page list column (\glspagelistwidth)
not setting the glossary title, i.e. omitting the title option in \printglossary[title={List of Abbreviations}]

None of the above are viable solutions for me, and I don't think I'm using any of them in a non-intended way.
Here's the MWE:
\documentclass[12pt,pdftex,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\KOMAoptions{%
    headings=optiontoheadandtoc,
    twoside=false,
}
\usepackage[headsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}

% without extrarowheight, the issue doesn't occur
\usepackage{array}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{3pt}

\usepackage[english]{babel}

% not loading xcolor also removes the spurious page!
\usepackage{xcolor}

% only needed when calculating the table column width, which is commented out
%\usepackage{calc}

\usepackage[automake,nopostdot,toc,nogroupskip,section=section]{glossaries}
\setacronymstyle{long-short}
\makeglossaries
% naming
%\newcommand{\myentryname}{Abbreviation}

% glossary table
\setglossarystyle{super3colheader}
% we define the left and right column width, and the description gets the rest.
% the manually created list of symbols uses the same dimensions.
%\newlength{\listlcolwidth}
%\setlength{\listlcolwidth}{0.18\textwidth}
\setlength{\glspagelistwidth}{0.13\textwidth}
%\setlength{\glsdescwidth}{1\textwidth - 3\tabcolsep - 1\listlcolwidth - 1\glspagelistwidth}
%\renewcommand*{\glsnamefont}[1]{\textbf{#1}}
%\newcommand{\glsheaderfont}[1]{\textbf{#1}}
%\renewcommand{\entryname}{Abbreviation}
%\renewenvironment{theglossary}%
%{%
%   \begin{supertabular}[l]{@{}p{\listlcolwidth}p{\glsdescwidth}p{\glspagelistwidth}@{}}%
%       \glsheaderfont{\myentryname}        & 
%       \glsheaderfont{\descriptionname}    & 
%       \glsheaderfont{\pagelistname}       \\
%   }%
%   {%
%   \end{supertabular}%
%}


\newacronym{a}{A}{Letter of the alphabet}
\newacronym{b}{A}{Letter of the alphabet}
\newacronym{c}{A}{Letter of the alphabet}
\newacronym{d}{A}{Letter of the alphabet}
\newacronym{e}{A}{Letter of the alphabet}
\newacronym{f}{A}{Letter of the alphabet}
\newacronym{g}{A}{Letter of the alphabet}
\newacronym{h}{A}{Letter of the alphabet}
\newacronym{i}{A}{Letter of the alphabet}
\newacronym{j}{A}{Letter of the alphabet}
\newacronym{k}{A}{Letter of the alphabet}
\newacronym{l}{A}{Letter of the alphabet}
\newacronym{m}{A}{Letter of the alphabet}
\newacronym{n}{A}{Letter of the alphabet}
\newacronym{o}{A}{Letter of the alphabet}
\newacronym{p}{A}{Letter of the alphabet}
\newacronym{q}{A}{Letter of the alphabet}
\newacronym{r}{A}{Letter of the alphabet}
\newacronym{s}{A}{Letter of the alphabet}
\newacronym{t}{A}{Letter of the alphabet}
\newacronym{u}{A}{Letter of the alphabet}
\newacronym{v}{A}{Letter of the alphabet}
\newacronym{w}{A}{Letter of the alphabet}
\newacronym{x}{A}{Letter of the alphabet}
\newacronym{y}{A}{Letter of the alphabet}
\newacronym{z}{A}{Letter of the alphabet}
\newacronym{aa}{A}{Letter of the alphabet}
\newacronym{ab}{A}{Letter of the alphabet}
\newacronym{ac}{A}{Letter of the alphabet}
\newacronym{ad}{A}{Letter of the alphabet}
\newacronym{ae}{A}{Letter of the alphabet}
\newacronym{af}{A}{Letter of the alphabet}
\newacronym{ag}{A}{Letter of the alphabet}
\newacronym{ah}{A}{Letter of the alphabet}
\newacronym{ai}{A}{Letter of the alphabet}
\newacronym{aj}{A}{Letter of the alphabet}
\newacronym{ak}{A}{Letter of the alphabet}
\newacronym{al}{A}{Letter of the alphabet}
\newacronym{am}{A}{Letter of the alphabet}
\newacronym{an}{A}{Letter of the alphabet}
\newacronym{ao}{A}{Letter of the alphabet}
\newacronym{ap}{A}{Letter of the alphabet}
\newacronym{aq}{A}{Letter of the alphabet}
\newacronym{ar}{A}{Letter of the alphabet}
\newacronym{as}{A}{Letter of the alphabet}
\newacronym{at}{A}{Letter of the alphabet}
\newacronym{au}{A}{Letter of the alphabet}
\newacronym{av}{A}{Letter of the alphabet}
\newacronym{aw}{A}{Letter of the alphabet}
\newacronym{ax}{A}{Letter of the alphabet}
\newacronym{ay}{A}{Letter of the alphabet}
\newacronym{az}{A}{Letter of the alphabet}


\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents \newpage

    \section{List of Symbols}\label{sec:symbols}
    % content isn't even needed
    \newpage
    
    \printglossary[title={List of Abbreviations}]
    \newpage
    
    \section{Introduction}

    \gls{a}
    \gls{b}
    \gls{c}
    \gls{d}
    \gls{e}
    \gls{f}
    \gls{g}
    \gls{h}
    \gls{i}
    \gls{j}
    \gls{k}
    \gls{l}
    \gls{m}
    \gls{n}
    \gls{o}
    \gls{p}
    \gls{q}
    \gls{r}
    \gls{s}
    \gls{t}
    \gls{u}
    \gls{v}
    \gls{w}
    \gls{x}
    \gls{y}
    \gls{z}
    % the glossary MUST have more than one page for the spurious blank page to occur
    \gls{aa}
    \gls{ab}
    \gls{ac}
    \gls{ad}
    \gls{ae}
    \gls{af}
    \gls{ag}
    \gls{ah}
    \gls{ai}
    \gls{aj}
    \gls{ak}
    \gls{al}
    \gls{am}
    \gls{an}
    \gls{ao}
    \gls{ap}
    \gls{aq}
    \gls{ar}
    \gls{as}
    \gls{at}
    \gls{au}
    \gls{av}
    \gls{aw}
    \gls{ax}
    \gls{ay}
    \gls{az}
    
\end{document}

Tried these fixes, which didn't work:

Remove page break before glossary
Can't get rid of blank page
Remove empty pages before glossary

I'd be happy if anyone knew a way to fix this.
